# Proof of bipartite graphs with $k$ edges

Tags: combinatorics

Let $b_k(n)$ be the number of bipartite graphs (without multiple edges) with $k$ edges on the vertex set $[n]$.  Show that: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}b_k(n)q^k\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sqrt{\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum^n_{i=0}(1+q)^{i(n-i)}{n\choose i}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Let $c_k(n)$ be the number of ways to choose a connected bipartite graph on $[n]$ with $k$ edges and $f_k(n)$ (respectively, $g_k(x)$)be the number of ways to choose a weak ordered partition $(A,B)$ of $[n]$ into two parts, and then choose a bipartite graph with $k$ edges on $[n]$ such that every edge goes from $A\to B$.

$$\text{Now, let } B(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\sum_{k\geq0}b_k(n)q^k\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Similar for $C(x)$, $F(x)$ and $G(x)$